# How to calculate this limit

Tags: combinatorics, limits, summation, fractions

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\left(\frac{k\binom{n}{k} }{n2^n+k}\right) $$

I tried to develop it, but I did not get anything concrete

Comment: What is $C_k$ ?

Comment: Do you mean $_kC_k$?

Comment: Combinations of n taken by k

Comment: I do not know much about the code and it's hard to get me the code

Comment: maybe \binom{n}{k}, $\binom{n}{k}$

Comment: note that the sum on $k$ of $\binom{n}{k}$ is equal to $2^n$

Comment: Note that $$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{k\binom{n}{k}}{n2^n+k}=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\binom{n-1}{k-1}}{2^n+\frac kn}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint. Note that
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{n}k\binom{n}{k}=D_x\left(\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^k\right)_{x=1}=D_x\left((1+x)^n\right)_{x=1}=n(1+1)^{n-1}=n2^{n-1}.$$
Therefore
$$\frac{n2^{n-1}}{n(2^n+1)}=\frac{1}{n(2^n+1)}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}k\binom{n}{k}\leq \sum_{k = 0}^{n}\frac{k\binom{n}{k} }{n2^n+k}\leq
\frac{1}{n2^n}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}k\binom{n}{k}=\frac{1}{2}$$
Now use the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).